# Есть ли готовые плагины с похожим интерфейсом?

Tags: cms, интерфейс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть личный кабинет с тремя ролями, преподавели, курсы, ученика, имеется статистика  и прочее. Каждая роль имеет свой уровень допуска к информации.

Что это за интерфейс? Есть ли похожие? Как реализовать такое приложение?

Comment: По картинке интерфейса вам никто не даст точного ответа, потому что на каждую cms может быть кастомный шаблон интерфейса. Как минимум нужен кода CMS

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin дали задание на пост джуна, вот думаю, что это может быть... мб опенкарт.... есть какие то предположение? Создание состоит в том что у меня есть скрины и материалы. и я должен сделать 3 роли в системе и каждого свои привилегии..

Comment: Так а CMS тогда вам зачем? Если не можете сделать сами и не понимаете задание, то, может быть, рановато?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin образование в украине оставляет желать лучшего...

Comment: @DarkHat не стоит кого-то обвинять. Информации в интернете более чем достаточно. В универах практике учат редко, а большинство джунов и вовсе формируются лет в 16. Самообучение и труд всё перетрут.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin а я по вашему зачем зашел на стек? узнать то, что не знаю и изучить одну из платформ, которую требуют современные ит фирмы.

Comment: @DarkHat не с того конца начинаете :)

Comment: @DarkHat изучите теорию, практикуйтесь на своих простеньких придуманных проектах. Потом вопросы, как реализовать проект по одному лишь скриншоту и двум строчкам описания, пропадут.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin нет друзей/знакомых, которые подсскажут, а самому все познавать в 3 раза дольше чем с помощью...

Comment: @DarkHat не надейтесь на друзей, не надейтесь на знакомых, и тем более не надейтесь на «образование». Но и на SO надеяться не стоит, пожалуй. Надейтесь только на себя.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin у моей подруги муж - Team Lead по IOS-develop, но живут в Таиланде......поэтому нету помощи.....

Comment: Почему не уточнить у работодателя требования к платформе? `изучить одну из платформ, которую требуют современные ит фирмы`. Не редко у фирм самопис, который будете изучать с нуля. Вы в каком сегменте хотите трудиться? Если в веб-студии, то изучайте какой-нибудь вордпресс и битрикс. Если серьезная - то изучайте yii2, symfony, laravel, и то что я перечислил - не CMS.

Comment: Еще уточните, на что претендуете - фрон разработчик, бек, или все вместе? Может им нужен фронт, тогда склепайте на HTML + JavaScript, больше и не нужно.

Comment: @TotalPusher 
Адаптивная вёрстка по макетам:
Технологии
FrontEnd: На выбор: Angular2 + Bootstrap или
React+ Redux + Bootstrap
BackEnd:На выбор:
Node js + MongoDB
или
ASP.NET (PostgreSQL)

Comment: Ну вот, сами ответили на свой вопрос. Вам не нужна CMS. CMS - это готовая система, на которую ставятся шаблоны, и дело в шляпе. Вам нужно изучать фреймворки для бекенда. И современные технологии для фронта. Опять же уточните у работодателя - подойдет ли верстка одной страницы CSS + HTML. Или вы не контактируете с ним, чисто по описанию вакансии? Если с вас требуют готовое решение - шлите таких, с джуна это требовать бессмысленно. Ну и по времени это у вас займет неделю+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для личного кабинета с ТРЕМЯ ролями CMS избыточна на 300%.
Там нужно-то всего от трех до 10 файлов, общая длина кода 32кб!
гуглите PDO+Registration+Auth
С другой стороны, судя по скрину, требуется полноценный сервис типа Преподаватели-Курсы-Ученики со всей статистикой и т.д. Такие вещи, я слышал от знакомых, люди клепают от 1 килограмма зеленых, наивно сидеть тут и ждать готового кода... Там пару простыней точно будет этого самого кода...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3gSZLCCYRGsRjhQZ2tPOHN5NWc/view есть видео, если интересно глянуть.

Comment: @DarkHat что то там дохрена скринов у вас для тестового задания. это скорее тестовый проект какой-то.

Comment: @teran какой вывод?) много хотят?))))

Comment: @DarkHat для подготовки такого "тестового задания", как тебе сказали, персонального нужно затратить весьма много времени. Продумать логику и требования к функциям  + отрисовать "дизайн". Так что либо дизайн - является тестовым заданием другого соискателя, либо у вас перед глазами скрины с вполне рабочего (разрабатываемого) проекта. Как-то странно, что надо в каждый день обсуждать разработку с этим человеком.  и да, хотят много. Выглядит как "раньше мы давали одинаковые, а счас у нас запара, и мы решили скинуть тебе новый проект целиком" :D но не знаю, я не смотрел там видео целиком.

Comment: @teran я вроде нашел, как это помойка делается.... meteor.js - будет время глянь на ютубе)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMSycC-g95g